# Keeping search result consistent across multiple transactions

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have to implement a requirement for a Java CRUD application where users want to keep their search results intact even if they do actions which affects the criteria by which the returned rows are matched.

Confused? Ok. Let me give you a familiar example. In Gmail if you do an advanced search on unread emails, you are presented with a list of matching results. Click on an entry and then go back to the search list. What happens is that you have just read that entry but it hasn't disappeard from the original result set. Only that line has changed from bold to normal.

I need to implement the exact same behaviour but the application is designed in such a way that any transaction is persisted first and then the UI requeries the db to keep in sync. The complexity of the application and the size of the database prevents me from doing just a simple in memory caching of the matching rows and making the changes both in db and in memory.

I'm thinking of solving the problem on the database level by creating an intermediate table in the Oracle database holding pointers to matching records and requerying only those records to keep the UI in sync with data. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle, if you open a cursor, the results of that cursor are static, regardless if another transaction inserts a row that would appear in your cursor, or updates or deletes a row that does exist in your cursor.

The challenge then is to not close the cursor if you want results consistent from when the cursor was opened.

Comment: However you can only fetch from a cursor once... You would need to open many cursors if the user intends to return to the search page several times.

Answer (score 3):

If the UI maintains a single session on the database, one solution is to use Global Temporary Tables in Oracle. When you execute a search, insert the unique IDs into the GTT, then the UI just queries the GTT.

If the UI doesn't keep the session open, you could do the same thing but with an ordinary table. Then, of course, you'd just have to add some cleanup code to remove old search results from the table.

Comment: That's a smart idea but needs some tweaks to fit the bill. The data access is via a connection pool so GTT isn't suitable. Also the suggested solution requires extensive changes in the data access layer which in turn could cause unwanted side effects and performance issues. I guess I need to create a self-populating temp table using a combination of trigger/stored procedure magic so that the data retention complexities are masked away from the code as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flashback query to read data from the past.  For example, `select * from employee as of timestamp to_timestap('01-MAY-2011 070000', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MISS');`

Oracle only stores this historical information for a limited period of time.  You'll need to look into your retention settings; the UNDO_RETENTION parameter, UNDO tablespace retention gaurantee and proper sizing, and also LOBs have their own retention setting.

Answer (score 2):

Create two connections to the database.

Set the first one to READ ONLY (using `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY`) do your searching from that connection but make sure you **never** end that transaction by issuing a commit or rollback.

As a read only transaction only sees the data as it was at the time the transaction started, the first connection will never see any changes to the database - not even committed ones.

Then you can do your updates in the second connection without affecting the results in the first connection.

If you cannot use two connections, you could implement the updates through stored procedures that use autonomous transactions, then you can keep the read only transaction open in the single connection you have.